# Where can I find the exercises to Andrew Ng's DL specialization?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I finished videos to Andrew Ng's Deep Learning specialization yesterday, and now I'd like to do some programming exercise. However, I can't find the dataset and problem description of assignments. I tried find them on Github, but the search result are all solutions to the assignments without datasets. Does anyone has the unsolved exercise(Problem description and datasets)? THANKS!

p.s. I'm not a native English speaker, so my writing may be confusing. Feel free to ask me if you don't understand.

Comment: Are you doing the course on Coursera or just watching the videos on YouTube? If you are using the YouTube videos you can't have access to the exercises. You could just google ```DeepLearning Specilisation Github``` and see other peoples notebooks on the exercises.

Comment: reply to @yuRa: Thanks! But it looks like that there are no unsolved exercises on Github. I want to find unsolved exercises so I can do them myself.

Comment: Then pay for the course its not free.